# Suggest type of an object based on a given title

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, geospatial

I am working on an Ember application that deals with geospatial data processing. Part of this project is importing a JSON object that describes a data layer which contains fields corresponding to data entries. For example, I suppose I am importing a data layer called "Laundry Facilities"; the JSON will look something like this:

```
 {
      key: "laundryFacilities",
      label: "Laundry Facilities",
      fields: [
        {
          "label": "Name of Facility",
          "key": "name",
        },
        {
          "label": "Number of Dryers",
          "key": "numberDryers",
        }
      ]
 }
```

At some point in my data import workflow, the user must specify a type for each field. For example, the type for "Name of Facility" would be a string, and the type for "Number of Dryers" would be an integer. I'd like to be able to provide a suggested type to the user based off of the `label` or `key` attribute rather than forcing them to specify the type for every field. Is there any kind of algorithm, package, framework, etc. that provides functionality for guessing a data type based off of something qualitative like a label describing the data field? Or does anyone know of another way I could implement this? I know not to expect 100% accuracy but even a rough type guess would be extremely helpful. Bonus points if it's an Ember addon.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write some simple heuristic, not much more complicated than a bunch of keywords mapping to types. As you've described, 'number' probably means a number type and 'name' likely means a 'name' type.

In general, you're describing a classification problem. This is going to be difficult to solve with a (presumably) small set of training examples. If you can get a decent number of examples of column names, I would first try a decision tree or a logistic regression, which would take the presence of certain words as features, and produce a data type as the output variable.